# How can i use thinc.types with spacy version 2

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-transformers, coreference-resolution

I am using `spacy version==2.2.4` for name entity recognition and wishes to use the same version for testing **custom spacy relation extraction pipeline**. But unfortunately, I am facing the below issue while running custom relation extraction model with the above spacy version.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thinc.types'
```

I have used [spacy github](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component) link to train the custom relation extraction pipeline. For training, I have used `spacy==3.1.4`.

Now, I need to connect two different models whereas Name entity recognition is trained on spacy version 2 whereas spacy relation extraction model works fine with spacy version 3.

**I did some debugging and here are my results**

1. I read in [spacy github issue 7219](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/7219) that to use the relation extraction model with  spaCy v2, use `spacy-transformers==0.6.2`. I did exactly the same but no success.There is [pypi link about spacy](https://pypi.org/project/spacy-transformers/) transformers which says that spacy transformers requires `spacy>=3.0`
2. I did not stopped researching there and went to another [spacy github issue 7910](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7910) which says use the `thinc version 8.0.3`. This version is not compatible with `spacy==2.2.4`

I am facing the issue to use spaCy v2 for testing custom spaCy relation extraction pipeline. If it is not possible then one of the solution would be to use the same spacy version on both end. I could easily implement this but there is another challenge which comes in between i.e also using neuralcoref in between which cannot be installed with spaCy v3. So any solution to this problem would help in solving that.

I am also thinking about using different environments for (NER + Coreference) and (Relation Extraction). Does this sounds a good solution.

Comment: It's not possible to install or run spacy v2 and v3 in the same virtual environment or to combine v2 and v3 models in any way.

Comment: @aab thanks for explanation. But still my question is that can we use the custom spacy relation extraction pipeline with spaCy v2.